# Rejoining University after 7 months - under F1

Tags: usa, visa, education

I am from India. I went to US a University in Spring 2014 for MS program under F1 Visa. But due to serious health issues, I had to leave US even before the start of the program in US.

Now, I have settled stuff. I am prepared to go and complete my course in this Fall. I will receive my I-20 in a week or so.

So, will I need to go through the same process of F1 Visa again? I know that under F1 status, I cannot be outside US for more than 5 months. So what will happen in my case?

Comment: Talk to your DSO at  your university. They must have dealt with such situation in the past.

Comment: This post has been around without resolution to any of the multiple questions posed.